# Does the "36 Days until Lightning Experience" notification mean that we have no option but to move to Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience

When logging into our production org today, I noticed a banner/notification at the top of the page that reads:

> 36 Days until Lightning Experience

While I am not 100% sure, I believe it is related to this "Auto Transition" article:

https://lightning-readiness-check.salesforce.com/onboarding/AutoTransitionFAQ_Admin

My research shows that while it may be possible to postpone the switch, according to the document above, the transition is inevitable some time in October 2019. Here's the final paragraph:

> If you postpone the transition now, be aware that the Turn On
>   Lightning Experience critical update will apply to your org. You’ll
>   automatically transition in October, 2019 and will see in-app messages
>   about the update in the meantime. See the Spring ‘19 Release Notes for
>   more details.

I scanned the '19 Release Notes, but didn't see anything that spoke specifically about this.

Is my understanding correct? Will we have no option but to be ready for Lightning Experience by October 2019 as it appears the transition will be forced?

Thank you.

Comment: Have checked out these two Spring '19 release notes about [reminders](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_ta_reminders.htm) and the related [critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_cruc_lex_turned_on.htm)?

Comment: Thanks Brent. So to prevent the transition, do we just need to uncheck the "Lighting Experience User" option in the users' profiles? If we do this, will those users still be switched to LEX weekly per the release notes?

Comment: If you are on Group edition, you may not be able to turn it off. In other editions, you should be able to (though you would need a custom profile).

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to.

If you don't want to move to Lightning automatically, you can set the Profile setting "Lightning Experience User" to false. If that setting is false, then users on that profile won't be automatically moved to Lightning.

Note that the standard profiles will have this enabled on the switchover. So, if you're not already using custom profiles, you should switch over now.

> **Which users are affected?**
>
> All users with the Lightning Experience User permission enabled are
>   affected by this critical update. This includes all users with:
>
> - Standard profiles, which automatically include the Lightning Experience User permission by default.
> - Custom profiles or permission sets that have the Lightning Experience User permission included. Custom profiles created before
>     Winter ‘16 do not include the Lightning Experience User permission.
>     Starting with Winter ‘16, any custom profile that was cloned from a
>     standard profile does include the user permission, but admins can edit
>     the profile to disable the permission. See Salesforce Help for info on
>     how to Set Up Users for Lightning Experience.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317946&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1